# Boundedness of smooth vector field

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I have a basic question about vector fields on Riemannian manfiold: Suppose we have a smooth vector field $\xi $ sending $ x \to  \xi_x \in  T_x \mathcal{X}$ defined on a compact subset $\mathcal{X}$ of the manifold? Can one assume $\|\xi_x\| \leq C$ for some constant $C$ unifolmly for all $x \in \mathcal{M}$?

Is there a proof of this or a counterexample?

Comment: Let $K\subset \mathcal X$ be the compact subset on which $\xi$ is defined. Then $\|\xi\|:K\to \mathbb R$ is a real-valued function on a compact topological space.

Comment: Thanks, i knew it was something simple .